# Drawing Graphs ALA Graphviz in QT via PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, data-visualization, graphviz

I need to draw Concept networks(nodes - edges - nodes can have text properties) from a data model and have it layed out nicely (using QT). I already have experience with graphviz, but i'm willing to learn something else if it works outa-da-box. What are my options ? I know I could generate a image and then draw that via a QLabel somehow. However, I am hoping there is a nice integrated API available that simplifies this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a fully interactive graph with `QGraphicsView`. That will probably be preferable than a static image in a `QLabel`. Qt has [an example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview-elasticnodes.html) for this particular case. You can build on it. PyQt version comes with installation inside `examples/graphicsview`.

Though, I don't know any ready-made widgets/api that works with graphviz.

Comment: Sounds like what I might be looking for +1

Answer (score 3):

I have made a library of Qt extension widgets - one of which is a node graph.  You are able to fully define how to draw your nodes for custom looks, or can control generically via member methods.  Feel free to have a look and use.

To get a feel for its look, the Orbiter application uses it to build database ORM graphs.  Thats the only example at the moment - but I am planning to get more docs up in the next couple of weeks.

You can see the Orbiter app here:

http://www.projexsoftware.com/software/orbiter/

The specific class is non-application specific and is called XNodeWidget, here's the beginning docs:

http://docs.projexsoftware.com/api/projexui/widgets/xnodewidget/

And information on how to get the library can be found here:

http://dev.projexsoftware.com/projects/projexui/

Lemme know if that works out!

Comment: That looks promising. I will surely look through the API.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/).
It allows to create your graph, layout it and draw it (either using matplotlib or graphviz)